# How to onSelect dropdown1 item to show different dropdown2 item in PowerApps?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula

Below is the canvas-app formula that I have tried but it does not work:

[image]

```
If(
    DisplayInspectorDropdown.Selected.Value = "Jonathan Soh",
    true,
    DisplayBuildingDropDown.Selected.Value = "EC - Empire Complex")
```

Please do take a look to improve the canvas-app formula!! Thanks

I have encountered this error:
[image: Please see the image here]

Comment: @Geshode I do not have high reputation to show image yet so could only place it in the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PowerApps you cannot directly "assign" a value to a control; a control can reference other controls or [variables](https://review.learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/working-with-variables), and they react to *changes* to those.

In the first dropdown, if the names in the `Inspector` table are already unique, then you don't need to use the `Distinct` function, you can set the Items property directly to `Inspector`. That will help when making the selection in the second dropdown.

On the second dropdown (`DisplayBuildingDropDown`) control, you need to update the `Items` expression so that it would filter the buildings based on the selection of the first one, something along the lines of

```
Filter(
    Building,
    inspectorID = DisplayInspectorDropDown.Selected.inspectorID)
```

Where `Building` is the name of the data source that contains the buildings that you want to display, and `inspectorID` is the name of the column within that data source that corresponds to the values in the first dropdown.

Comment: How doesn't it work? Can you provide more information on what you see?

Comment: I have updated the post with an image on the error encountered @carlosfigueira

Comment: The Filter expression would be for the `Items` property of the *second* dropdown (`DisplayBuildingDropDown`), since it filters the values from the Building table based on the value of the first one.

Comment: I still have an error in the InspectorName ... @carlosfigueira

Comment: Is `InspectorName` the name of the column that has the inspector for the building table? You should use the name from your table.

Comment: Filter(
    Building,
    Inspector.'name ' = DisplayInspectorDropDown.Selected.Result) @carlosfigueira like this?

Comment: What are the columns of the Building table?

Comment: building, location, buildingID, inspectorID @carlosfigueira

Comment: In this case you'll need to use the `inspectorID` column - which I guess corresponds to the column with the same name in the Inspector table... I've updated my answer.